# Scraping pages with different data element and all span tag have the same name

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

The problem I am facing is that different pages have different data elements, for ex: [link 1](https://gepris.dfg.de/gepris/projekt/5214212?language=en) and [link 2](https://gepris.dfg.de/gepris/projekt/268853?language=en). As you can see, first link has `applicant` but not the second link, and there are many more under the project description. And they use the same `span` class and value. So how do I scrape them under the variable I want?
For example:

```
applicant= response.xpath('//.......')  #I want the applicant data here
```

I want to get applicant data here. But i couldn't use the `div[index]` format because different pages will have different data elements. The `span` class and value are the same so I couldn't get the data I want using the specific name.

My attempt on the 2nd link:

```
def parse_product(self, response):
   title = response.xpath('//div[@id="detailseite"]//div[@class="details"]/h3/text()').extract()
   area = response.xpath('//div[@class="firstUnderAntragsbeteiligte"]/span[@class="value"]/text()').extract()
   website = response.xpath('//div[@class="details"]//span[@class="value"]/a/@href').extract()
   identifier = response.xpath('//div[@class="projektnummer"]/span[@class="value"]/text()').extract()
   description = response.xpath('//div[@id="projekttext"]/text()').extract()
   programme = response.xpath('//div[@id="projektbeschreibung"]/div[2]/span[@class="value"]/text()').extract()
   institution = response.xpath('//div[@id="projektbeschreibung"]/div[3]/span[@class="value"]/a/text()').extract()
   institution_add = response.xpath('//div[@id="projektbeschreibung"]/div[3]/span[@class="value"]/text()').extract()
   spokeperson = response.xpath('//div[@id="projektbeschreibung"]/div[4]/span[@class="value"]/a/text()').extract()
   spokeperson_add = response.xpath('//div[@id="projektbeschreibung"]/div[4]/span[@class="value"]/text()').extract() 
   scientist = response.xpath('//div[@id="projektbeschreibung"]/div[5]/span[@class="value"]/a/text()').extract()
   programme_contact = response.xpath('//div[@class="dfg_contact"]/span[2]/span/a/text()').extract()
```

html code for  1st link:

```
    <div class="details">
       <h3>Symbioses in Macaranga: ontogeny and partner conflicts</h3>
       <div>
          <span class="name">
          Applicant
          </span>
          <span class="value">
             <a class="intern" href="/gepris/person/1174218">Professor Dr. Ulrich  Maschwitz</a>                                                                                        
          </span><!-- value -->
    </div>
    <div class="firstUnderAntragsbeteiligte">
         <span class="name">Subject Area</span>
         <span class="value">
    Zoology                                                                                                                                                         
         </span>
    </div>
    <div>
         <span class="name">Term </span>
         <span class="value">
         from 1999 to 2002
         </span><!-- value -->
    </div>
    <div class="projektnummer">
         <span class="name">Project identifier</span>
         <span class="value">Deutsche Forschungsgemeinschaft (DFG) - Projekt number 5214212</span>
    </div>
    </div>
```

html code for 2nd link:

```
            <div class="details">
                <h3>
                GRK 6:&nbsp;
                Spatial Statistics
                </h3>
                <div class="firstUnderAntragsbeteiligte">
                    <span class="name">Subject Area</span>
                    <span class="value">
                    Mathematics
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="name">Term </span>
                    <span class="value">
                    from 1997 to 2003
                    </span><!-- value -->
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span class="name">Website</span>
                    <span class="value">
                <a class="extern" href="http://www.mathe.tu-freiberg.de/math/inst/stoch/Gradu/index.html" title="Website" target="_blank">
                    Homepage
                </a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="projektnummer">
                    <span class="name">Project identifier</span>
                    <span class="value">Deutsche Forschungsgemeinschaft (DFG) - Projekt number 268853</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want it like this:

```
Title : Symbioses in Macaranga: ontogeny and partner conflicts
Applicant: Professor Dr. Ulrich Maschwitz
Subject Area:Zoology
Term : from 1999 to 2002
Project identifier:Deutsche Forschungsgemeinschaft (DFG) - Projekt number 5214212

Title : GRK 6:  Spatial Statistics
Subject Area : Mathematics
Term : from 1997 to 2003
Website : http://www.mathe.tu-freiberg.de/math/inst/stoch/Gradu/index.html
Project identifier : Deutsche Forschungsgemeinschaft (DFG) - Projekt number 268853
```

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML in your post itself, don’t just link to the pages.

Comment: No, not as images. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11301900.

Comment: Also, can you highlight what data you’re trying to get?

Comment: edited my code.. I am trying to get the applicant data here. but due to different pages have different element, I couldn't use the `div[1]`. And they all have the same span class

Comment: Can you be more specific? What applicant data? All I have to work off of is that HTML, and I can only see the word “applicant” once. How do you know which data you need?

Comment: sorry if i didn't explain well. I want to extract every data under `span` value

Comment: Do you mean the contents of all the span tags which have/are part of the value class?

Comment: i have updated the result i want..

Comment: check out my current attempt

Comment: Aah, now things are a but clearer. Yes, the spans have the same class, but that’s fine! As far as I can tell there aren’t any indistinguishable span elements. All you need to do is iterate over the outer divs, and associate the contents of each span with class “name” with the contents of the sibling span with class “value”. They form a key-value pair or mapping, think of them like dictionaries in Python.

Comment: in every `<div>` you have two `<span>` - get both and use text from first `<span>` to recognize what you get in second `<span>`.

Comment: alright thanks to both of you will try it out

Comment: @adrian I’ll give it a shot myself tomorrow :)

Comment: @AlexanderCécile thanks in advance! but here's the thing, after getting the data i need to pass the output to c# app... since every page has different number of data attribute, how do I add it into my class? for ex: if the first page scraped doesn't have attribute `applicant` which makes it only 4 attributes, while the second page scraped has attribute `applicant` which makes it 5 attributes, previously other websites that i have scraped have fixed number of attributes, then i just increment `i+5` then should be done, how about this

Comment: @adrian I’m not sure I understand the `i+5`. This shouldn’t be an issue if the pages generally have similar attributes (you’ll need to check the data for that). Here’s what I’m thinking: Make a dict of attribute:value for a bunch of pages. Compare them. Do they almost all have the same set of attributes? Then use a class or namedtuple. Are the attributes all over the place? Might be an issue, we’ll have to give it more thought.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < str.Length; i = i + 4)
            {
                lstGrant.Add(new GrantDFG()
                {
                    Title = str[i],
                    Area = str[i + 1],
                    Website = str[i + 2],
                    Identifier = str[i + 3],
                   
                });
            };   so previously i insert the output from the data scraped into array then add into a class, every page has 4 attributes so every `i+4` means it is a new page scraped, but in this case every page has different number of attributes i can't increment like that

Comment: @adrian Can you share some more examples of the data, including the case with multiple indistinguishable span tags you mentioned?

Comment: sorry i dont get what you mean

Comment: my previous case was data with fixed number of data attributes with specific class/id on the tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204315/discussion-between-alexander-cecile-and-adrian).

Answer (score 1):

Let say you want a JSON output:

```py
features = response.xpath('//div[@class="details"]//'
               'span[@class="name"]'
               '//text()').getall()
values = response.xpath(
        '//div[@class="details"]//'
        'span[@class="value" and'
        'not(contains(text() , "\t"))]'
        '/text()'
        '| //div[@class="details"]'
        '//span[@class="value"]'
        '/a/text()').getall()

out = dict(zip(features, values))
```

As a output you will have a JSON object contains `class="name"` as names and `class="value"` as values.
**Update:** for issue you mentioned in comment `parse()` would be:

```py
def parse(self, response):
    res = {}
    for detail in response.xpath('//div[@class="details"]/div'):
        items = list()
        for item in detail.xpath('./span[@class="value"  and contains(text(), "") or @class="name"]/text()').getall():
            if item.strip() != '':
                items.append(item.strip())
        res.update({
            items[0]: items[1:]
        })
```

`res` value at the end:

```py
{'Applicants': ['Universität zu Köln', 'Department für Geowissenschaften', 'Geographisches Institut', 'Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz Universität Hannover', 'Institut für Wirtschafts- u
nd Kulturgeographie'], 'Subject Area': ['Human Geography'], 'Term': ['since 2015'], 'Project identifier': ['Deutsche Forschungsgemeinschaft (DFG) - Projekt number 275355279']}
```

Comment: but what if some of the `class=value` doesnt have text. instead they have child `a`.. you can see it on the first span value of first html code i posted

Comment: You can reach that by `//text()` means take text of any child and grandchildren instead of `/text()` that takes only first child text.

Comment: but apparently not, it will leave out empty space for the first span class text()... the output is like this `{'Applicant': '', 'SubjectArea': 'ProfessorDr.UlrichMaschwitz', 'Term': '', 'Projectidentifier': 'Zoology', 'DFGProgramme': 'from1999to2002', 'InternationalConnection': 'DeutscheForschungsgemeinschaft(DFG)-Projektnumber5214212', 'ParticipatingPersons': 'ResearchGrants'}`

Comment: aha, I got it, it takes some extra characters, let me see.

Comment: Why the yield? What does `.getall()` do? Also this code is rather fragile, a single other span with class “name” anywhere in the program and the entire thing breaks. I would have used xpath to get the parent of the name and value spans, then grab each of them manually. That loop should have been a `for in`, or, even better, just `dict(zip())`.

Comment: `.getall()` is same as `.extract()`, thanks for advises. @AlexanderCécile

Comment: @Piron What does `.extract()` do, then? Aren’t you using lxml?

Comment: no I am using Scrapy, visit [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html), `getall()` always returns a list of results.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile hey can you explain more on your approach?

Comment: @Piron Aah that makes sense, no wonder I was confused! I’ll take a look, I’ve never actually used Scrapy before.

Comment: @adrian The potential issues, or the whole “grab the parent div” thing? In any case, it’ll have to wait a few hours, I need some sleep ;)

Comment: @Piron ur code works well in this case. thanks anyway

Comment: @AlexanderCécile the grab parent div thing.. sure thing take your time as long as you are willing to help :)

Comment: @Piron but here's the thing, after getting the data i need to pass the output to c# app... since every page has different number of data attribute, how do I add it into my class? for ex: if the first page scraped doesn't have attribute applicant which makes it only 4 attributes, while the second page scraped has attribute applicant which makes it 5 attributes. Previously other websites that i have scraped have fixed number of attributes, then i just increment i+5 then should be done, how about in this case that have different number of attributes

Comment: @adrian I just answered your other comment on the main post actually

Comment: @Piron check it out this webpage https://gepris.dfg.de/gepris/projekt/275355279?language=en , for the applicant `span tag` has 2 child underneath, then the code won't work, this website is damn troublesome lolol

Comment: @adrian That’s unfortunate

Comment: @adrian OK let me see.

Comment: @adrian I've added a update to the answer, it works well with the link you shared, I hope you face no trouble again, wish you luck.